# Exporting formData from React to Spring boot backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data

React code for build jsonBlob object

```
function  jsonBlob(obj) {
  return new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj)], {
    type: "application/json",
  });
}

 exportFTP = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", jsonBlob(this.state.ipData));
    alert("Logs export to FTP server")

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/uploadfiles",
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json ,text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    });
  };
```

Spring boot backend that accepts for frontend request

```
public class UploadFile {
    @Autowired
    private FTPClient con;

    @PostMapping("/api/auth/uploadfiles")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        try {
            boolean result = con.storeFile(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File store failed");
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

I want to figure out when I called the function from the frontend it's **working properly** but I change the state its **doesn't send** the object to the backend while the file appears in the directory. if I delete the file then only send it again and save it on the directory.
**How I save multiple files while doesn't delete the previous ones**

Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React application I used props to pass the file name from a different state and make sure to remove,

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
```

Main function in React,

```
 exportFTP = ({props from different state}) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", jsonBlob(this.state.ipData),{You can use this parm for pass name});
    alert("Logs export to FTP server")

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/uploadfiles",
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json ,text/plain, */*"
 
      },
    });
  };
```

And back end code I used same to get the original name then Its appears with the right name.

```
con.storeFile(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream());
```

Chears !!

Answer (score 1):

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
```

Don't set the `Content-Type` yourself when posting a FormData.
The `Content-Type` needs to contain the boundary value that's generated by a FormData
(example: `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzCZHB3yKO1NSWzsn`).
It will automatically be inserted when posting a FormData instance, so leave this header out.

---

When you append blobs to a formdata then it will default the filename to just `"blob"`

On the backend you seems to override the file all the time:

```
con.storeFile(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream());
```

Generate a new unik name if you want to keep all files

---

of topic but why not go with the fetch api? Smaller footprint. don't require a hole library...

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/uploadfiles', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json ,text/plain, */*'
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time @Endless for this con.storeFile(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream()); I cant properly understand to make change because Im beginner here. I tried use string instead of file.getoriginalfilename() but its doesn't work

Comment: I used boolean result = con.storeFile(String.valueOf(file), file.getInputStream()); Its allows to save multiple files but same name appears.